# Removing and Adding classes with button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a button to remove the class `.computer-off` and add `.computer-on` and vice versa when clicked again. I've tried quite a few approaches, but to no avail. Here's one approach:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="computer-screen" class="computer-off">

    <button onclick="computerPower()" class="power-button">Power</button>

</div>
```

**JS**:

```
function computerPower() {
    if ( $("#computer-screen").hasClass('computer-off') ) {
        document.getElementById('computer-screen').removeClass('computer-off').addClass('computer-on');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("computer-screen").removeClass('computer-on').addClass('computer-off');
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: `document.getElementById('computer-screen').removeClass('computer-off')`: nodelists don't have add/removeclass methods. You seem to be very confused as to the difference between jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: I certainly agree with that, excuse my ignorance. I tried so many things, this was a combination of a lot of approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest, given that you *appear* to (be trying to) use jQuery:

```
$('#power').on('click', function() {
  $('#computer-screen').toggleClass('computer-off computer-on');
});
```

```js
$('#power').on('click', function() {
  $('#computer-screen').toggleClass('computer-off computer-on');
});
```

```css
#computer {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0;
}
#computer-screen {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  height: 15em;
}
.computer-off {
  background-color: #000;
}
.computer-on {
  background-color: #060;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.0em #060;
}
#power {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.computer-on + #power {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #666;
}
#power::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  left: 0.9em;
  right: 0.9em;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#power::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.2em solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  left: 0.3em;
}
#computer-screen.computer-on + #power::before {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#computer-screen.computer-on + #power::after {
  border-color: #0f0;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="computer">
  <div id="computer-screen" class="computer-off"></div>
  <div id="power"></div>
</div>
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('power').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var screen = document.getElementById('computer-screen');
  screen.classList.toggle('computer-off');
  screen.classList.toggle('computer-on');
});
```

```js
document.getElementById('power').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var screen = document.getElementById('computer-screen');
  screen.classList.toggle('computer-off');
  screen.classList.toggle('computer-on');
});
```

```css
#computer {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0 0;
}
#computer-screen {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  height: 15em;
}
.computer-off {
  background-color: #000;
}
.computer-on {
  background-color: #060;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.0em #060;
}
#power {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.computer-on + #power {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #666;
}
#power::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  left: 0.9em;
  right: 0.9em;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#power::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.2em solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  left: 0.3em;
}
#computer-screen.computer-on + #power::before {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#computer-screen.computer-on + #power::after {
  border-color: #0f0;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="computer">
  <div id="computer-screen" class="computer-off"></div>
  <div id="power"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- jQuery:

  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been able to help.